# UI5 display placeholder when editable is false

Tags: sapui5

I am using an Input tag where editable=false, but problem is placeholder is not visible.
There's a click event on the input field.
Is there a way to show placeholder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your code to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your field is called "email", then you write the placeholder text in the i18n file:

```
placeholder.email=Enter Email
```

In your XML file use [Expression Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html)

```
<Input type="Text" placeholder="{i18n>placeholder.email}" value="{= ${model>/email} === '' ? ${i18n>placeholder.email} : ${model>/email}}" editable="false"/>
```

If the value(`model>/email`) empty, the value will be the placeholder text(`i18n>placeholder.email`).

Expression Binding

```
{= ${model>/email} === '' ? ${i18n>placeholder.email} : ${model>/email}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A placeholder is there to help users **when entering data.**

> The placeholder [...] is a short hint (a word or short phrase) to help the user with **data entry**.
> [(Source)](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/input-field/#placeholder)

If the input field is not editable in the first place, you shouldn't rely on placeholder. Instead, consider to use `sap.m.Label` as an alternative.

> **Avoid** using the placeholder attribute as an alternative to a label. [...] Labels are necessary to indicate the meaning of the form fields when the placeholders are no longer visible. [(Source)](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/input-field/#placeholder1)

Placeholder is **not** a replacement for labels.