# How do I add the click event to the input field?

Tags: javascript, input, click, sapui5

I want to add a button property to an entry. For example;

I have an input field that cannot be edited:

[image: Screenshot1]

When I press the keyboard button it becomes editable:

[image: Screenshot2]

When the user clicks on the entry field without the need for a different button, it must run a different function. For example barcode scanner. Can an input that is not editable trigger a function? Or can an editable input trigger any function? How do I do this?

As in [this application](https://ijmacgregor.github.io/sapui5-barcode-scanner/), the barcode event should be triggered by the input field, not the button.

Comment: _> I want to trigger an event when I click ..._ --> Is that what _you_ want? Or do the **target users** want this - being aware that this "feature" deviates from the common Fiori UX design? How should the user know that an uneditable field is clickable without experimenting with the mouse?

Comment: Let me ask my question more accurately. What I want to do is create a barcode reader. When the user clicks on the input field, the barcode scanner must first be opened. If the user wants to enter a barcode number manually, they must make the field editable with the keyboard button next to the entry. I'm editing my question.*

Comment: The issue is that users might have difficulties to discover that the non-editable input field is actually clickable in the first place. And since [non-editable input fields cannot even show a placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64749869/5846045), **your scanner feature becomes completely hidden** behind an obscured click event somewhere. It gets worse if the app is running in a mobile device since there is no hand-indicator from the mouse. I added an alternative solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259716/5846045

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my comment, the UX of the current approach in the question is highly questionable:

- It's missing a *signifier*. There is no clear indication that only **that** non-editable field - in contrast to all other non-editable ones - triggers *something* once clicked.
- Users, who'd prefer entering the barcode manually, would need to click on the keyboard-button first to make the input field editable, and then, once again, click on the input field to enter data.

Instead, consider to offer **both** options (entering manually and triggering the camera to scan) within a single input field via its value-help (<kbd>F4</kbd>) action:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
], async (Fragment) => {
  "use strict";
  
  const control = await Fragment.load({
    definition: `<form:SimpleForm xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      editable="true"
      layout="ColumnLayout">
      <Label text="Barcode Number" />
      <Input width="12rem"
        textAlign="Center"
        placeholder="XXXXXXXXX"
        showValueHelp="true"
        valueHelpIconSrc="sap-icon://bar-code"
        valueHelpRequest="alert('Scanner triggered!')"
      />
    </form:SimpleForm>`,
  });
  
  control.placeAt("content");
}));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.layout"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody"></body>
```

[image: UI5: sap.m.Input with barcode scanner as a value help icon]

The value help icon can be set to a barcode one by assigning `"sap-icon://bar-code"` to the `valueHelpIconSrc` property (available since v1.84.0) in `sap.m.Input`.

This approach is beneficial for both - users and developers - because the behavior is now consistent with common user input scenarios, improving familiarity, and for developers, it highly reduces maintenance costs since there is less customization.

---

**If** the target UI5 version is lower than 1.84.0 or **if the barcode has a fixed length**, the control needs to be extended with the method `addEndIcon`. I explained this in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55314734/5846045). Here is an example with an extended `sap.m.MaskInput`:

[image: UI5: Extended sap.m.MaskInput with barcode scanner as a value help icon]
<sup>See https://embed.plnkr.co/EzlF2tkvalJWvSEn?preview</sup>

Comment: This example doesn't work for version 1.52.13. Is a different control possible for the lower version?

Comment: @shrgrl The API `addEndIcon` is available [since 1.58](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/8e208024c9115983c86e416e9777e53023918b8a). According to the [version overview](https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html), support for 1.52 ends this year. I could, of course, edit my answer just for the soon-to-be-deprecated version, but I'd rather encourage upgrading the UI5 version to the latest LTS-version (1.84) to benefit from overall performance improvements, stability, and security. UI5 takes backwards compatibility very seriously so that upgrading won't break existing applications.

Answer (score 0):

If your non-editable `input` is non-editable because it has a `disabled` attribute, you can't attach mouse events to it. (Actually you can, but it won't fire mouse events.)

If you want to fire a click event, you can add the event listener to a parent element, like a `div` in my example below.

Although it works in Chrome without it, you also need to set `pointer-events` to `none` on the `input` to make the clicks fall through to the parent element in Firefox.

```js
const parentDiv = document.querySelector("div");
const input = document.querySelector("input");

parentDiv.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  input.removeAttribute("disabled");
  input.focus();
  // or you can open the barcode scanner, etc.
});
```

```css
input {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

input[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" value="disabled field" disabled>
</div>
```

It could also work with `label` if the `label` contains the `input`:

```html
<label>Barkod No:
  <input type="text" value="disabled field" disabled>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that's not what I want. I'll check it the editable event with the button. But when I click on the input field, I want to trigger a different function.  eg. barcode scanner

Comment: Well, you can do anything inside the event handler.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, replacing the displayDate funcion with your own enable function:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);
```

Which then calls the CSS change:

```
input[type="text"]:enabled {
```

}

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: They want to trigger an event when someone clicks on the not-editable input field, not the button.

Comment: It's the same. Just change the "myBtn" to the ID of your input field

Comment: It's not the same. Disabled elements don't fire mouse events. Check my answer.